# $X^*/ Y^\perp$ is isometric isomorphic to $Y^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

let $X$ be a normed space.and $Y$ is subspace of $X$.then prove that

$X^*/ Y^\perp$ is isometric isomorphic to $Y^*$

where $Y^\perp=\{f\in X^* :f(x)=0 \ \forall\  x\in Y$

$h:X^*/ Y^\perp \to Y^*$ such that  $h(f+Y^\perp)=\tilde{f}$, where $\tilde{f}$ is restriction of $f$
 on $Y$. i know it is isomorphism.
but how  is this map isometry.i know i have to use Hann Banach theorem. but i am not able to write precisely the argument.

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $\psi \in  Y^*$, the class of all extensions
$\phi \in X^*$ is a coset in $X^*/Y^{\perp}$. It is clear that this correspondence between $Y^*$ and $X^*/Y^{\perp}$ is an isomorphism. Let prove that is an isometry. In fact, $\|\psi\| \leq \|\phi\|$ for
every extension $\phi$. By the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is at least one
extension for which $\|\psi\| = \|\phi\|$. In other words, for the coset of extensions of $\psi$, the infimum defining the norm is attained and is equal to $\|\psi\|$.

Peter L. Duren - Theory of Hp spaces.